# On setting iOS simulator default location from Edit Scheme, does it affect the device location update?

Tags: ios6, xcode4.5, cllocationmanager

Since I was getting error "Location Manager Error : (KCLErrorDomain error 0)" I edit the scheme to set default location. i.e. **Scheme > Edit Scheme > Options > Allow Location Simulation** checked set default location.

Does it affect the device to get its location from GPS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, its affecting the device location as well, i verified with `https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/LocateMe/Introduction/Intro.html` when i simulator it on the device it still give the same location which is configured by Scheme > Edit Scheme > Options > Allow Location Simulation not the actual location of device.